# TypeError: channel.isText is not a fuction

Tags: discord.js

```js
        interaction.guild.channels.create(`${interaction.values}-${interaction.user.username}`, { //ticket_name
          parent: config.ticketparent,
          topic: interaction.user.id,
          permissionOverwrites: [{
              id: interaction.user.id,
              allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL','SEND_MESSAGES'],
            },
            {
              id: config.ticketrole,
              allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
            {
              id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
              deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
          ],
          type: 'GUILD_TEXT', //i think the error is from here in past i have here text but not i have GUILD_TEXT
        })
```

please can someone tell me if i fixed the error as you can see i told tha i change channel create type to GUILD_TEXT from text the erro that i got is here https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1092463941818523738/1092516915462819840/image.png

if the screenshop does't load reply to this message and tell me tou give you new screenshot

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just have to update your discord.js version.

Using npm, if you have version:

- v14: npm i discord.js@latest
- v13: npm i discord.js@v13-lts

It's due to a discord change which totally changed how discord.js handle things.